# Notice: Undefined index: country in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Gateway/Validator/CountryValidator.php on line 54

Tags: magento2

Site is experiencing an issue where a specific payment method returns the following error when selected during checkout:
`Notice: Undefined index: country in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-payment/Gateway/Validator/CountryValidator.php on line 54`

Contents of line 54 in said file:

```
if (!in_array($validationSubject['country'], $availableCountries)) {
    $isValid =  false;
}
```

Could this be related to a change made to allowed countries under Stores > Configuration > General > Allow Countries? Two additional countries were added: United States and United Kingdom. Prior to this, the only countries allowed were Australia and New Zealand.

I've tried a few standard things, such as running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`. I've reindexed and cleaned and flushed the cache.

I thought if I removed the added countries from being allowed, the issue may correct itself, with no luck.

No other changes to code or files has been made and this error only occurs on the one payment method, which uses a gateway to process payment. Payment methods not using a gateway work, as does PayPal.

The payment gateway in question has been set to only allow specific countries (AU & NZ) and has worked for about a year until now. Setting the gateway to accept all allowed countries corrects the issue.

Comment: you can `var_dump($availableCountries)` to check available Countries and try to add missing countries in payment gateway settings if available..

Comment: @Pawan I neglected to mention that the problem gateway has allowed countries set to just Australia and New Zealand. I've updated my question with those details, but setting the gateway to allow all allowed countries fixes the issue.

Comment: glad to know now it is working  :)

Comment: @Pawan Well yes, it is now working, though not satisfactorily. The way I see it, a gateway should allow just specific countries, since that's an option in M2. I shall continue to troubleshoot the issue and see if I can find a fix or at the very least a workaround.